# remove <br> from specific div

Tags: jquery

I need to remove break from a specific `div`, i know how to remove all breaks with

`$('br').remove();​`

But I need to keep some breaks elsewhere on the page ,

How would I remove the breaks from a `div` with the id "grape1" and "grape12" but leave all others  intact?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$('#grape1,#grape12').find('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$('br', '#grape1, #grape12').remove();​
```

The second argument in the `$` selector allows you to filter your search to a given subset, instead of the entire DOM.  In this case we tell jQuery to only look inside the `grape1` and `grape12` divs.  This will match all br's in those div's.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myPvT/)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but for some reason it didnt work?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work for you.  I added a jsfiddle to show it does work.

Answer (score 2):

If that doesn't work (as happened in my case also) it's probably because the `<br>` are generated by some scripts after the JS `.remove()` code execution.

To check if I was right I set a quite long timeout and all my unwanted `<br>` disappeared after that time.
So, in the end I just decided to put a simple CSS

`#grape1 br, #grape12 br {
    display: none;
}`

and eveybody's happy =)